# Issue with Loop and display of list Using Salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, visual-flows, flowscreen, flow-screen-component

I have the below salesforce flow:

[image]

What the flow is trying to do:

1. On the first screen get the Account name and account number
   [image]
2. If Acc number = 1 then assign acc values to a record variable var_account1
   [image]

[image]
3. For default outcome, I assign acc name&number to a record variable var_account2

[image]

4. Add var_account2 to a list
   [image]
5. create a default account variable with Name=Default and Number = 1111. I use the same var_account2 to store it
   [image]
6. Add var_account2 to list
   [image]
7. Loop through the list and store the merge field into a text list
   [image]
8. Display the content of the text list with account Name
   [image]

[image]

**The problem:** My issue is when going through the flow, I don't see all the account Name displayed after the loop. This is especially when the case when I assign account where the account number is not equal to 1 and when a default account is created.

All I want is to loop through the list of accounts and display only the account Name. This is to give the user a summary that what Account has been added. Is there any other way to do this?

Debug Mode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**In above step default Account doesn't show up**

[image]

[image]

**Now Acc3 , that I added doesn't show up**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of loop is the culprit. This is what your current Flow says

- For each item in your list_account variable

  - Add to your text collection variable
  - Go to the screen

You've never actually waited for the **end** of your loop.

What you want is

- For each item in your list_account variable

  - Add to your text collection variable
  - After loop is finished (*after last item*)

    - Go back to screen

You need to make your assignment in the loop closed and then add a connector from the Loop element to the screen element for `After Last Item`.

[image]

Then, while you enter your information - it'll appropriately loop through the whole list (to assign your merge collection variable) before then going back to the screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked!