# Data-driven survey interface using Screen Flows?

Tags: screen-flow, repeat, data-repeater, roadmap

I'm interested in building a lightweight survey interface in Flow which is **data-driven** -- i.e. the Questions in the survey are dynamically pulled/built from a Question__c object rather than hardcoded in the Flow. The Flow would only have 1 screen and all Question records would be displayed in that screen underneath each other (maybe ordered based on some Order__c custom field on the Question record).

I'm essentially looking for a way to mimic the `for:each` LWC directive within Screen Flows.

**Has anyone found a way to do this?** I'm open to using a managed/unmanaged package if one exists which can enable this.

If not, does anyone have any insight about the roadmap and when this might become available? The new "Repeater" component looks like it might evolve to provide this functionality, but I can't be sure. If Salesforce don't provide a way to do this dynamic iteration for screen components in the next 6 months, then I'll go ahead with a LWC, but just want to understand what the current thinking is.

It does look like [I'm not the only one interested in accomplishing this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392783/screen-inside-loop-in-salesforce-lightning-flow), but I haven't heard of anyone being able to achieve this successfully yet.

Comment: Flows support looping over collection variables. And there's the datatable component you can use for presenting stuff in a given screen if you want them all on the one screen, instead of a separate screen per question.

Comment: and [OOTB behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.task_add_display_logic.htm&type=5) isn't sufficient?

Comment: @cropredy that's not exactly OOTB since its a different product with licenses, but yes I have considered using a more traditional survey product and it is a possibility, but not a great fit right now (for many reasons).

Comment: @PhilW looping over a collection doesn't allow me to build a single screen with all records (Questions) displayed the same way it would if you used a for:each block in an LWC or Visualforce page. That's why I'm asking if anyone has been able to accomplish this. 

The datatable component is very limited in how it can be used and doesn't let a User inline edit records. I am exploring possibly using a custom enhanced datatable component to do this, but the table-like structure isn't a great user experience.

Comment: If you have to present all questions so they are visible together, go custom. But if you can show them one at a time you can easily do so, and can likely arrange for automatic progress on answer with some careful design of logic and reactive handling (not sure, haven't tried).

Comment: I stand corrected, not exactly OOTB is correct; though `SurveyResponsePack` is fairly inexpensive for low volume surveys. `Feedback Management` licenses are (really) expensive though